# Error while running ORB_SLAM2 as a ROS node

Tags: ros, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the tutorial provided in this [link](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2), I am trying to run ORB_SLAM as a ROS node in ROS Indigo. After executing the line /.build_ros.sh, I am facing a list of errors,

```
/home/ubuntu_16/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM2/../../../Thirdparty/g2o/g2o/types/../core/jacobian_workspace.h:30:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/build.make:118: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/src/ros_rgbd.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/src/ros_rgbd.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RGBD.dir/all] Error 2
```

I am unable to get rid of these problem, if someone has faced the same, please help. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267867/error-while-running-orb_slam2-as-a-ros-node/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not appear to have the build dependency Eigen installed on your system. Or else it's not in your include_dirs argument.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0